# Oculus Quest 2 Native C++ Adding the SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, oculus

I'm trying to configure "Android Studio" to develope Native C++ Apps for a Oculus Quest 2 Mobile platform.

On the page [Native Development - Get Started with the Platform SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/pc/ps-get-started/)
and under the

> Configure Your Development Environment for Mobile Development

The documention states the following.

> The Oculus Platform SDK provides a loader that enables .so signature
> verification and graceful detection of the Oculus Runtime. To use the
> loader, add the SDK location to the manager
> ([InstallFolder]/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libovrplatformloader.so).

I've downloaded the ovr_platfrm_sdk_40.0 and unzipped to a folder on my local drive.

However, I have no idea how to use the SDK Manager to do the above.
I've tried to change the SDK Location in the manager and it comes up with a warning that the selected folder (The one I downloaded) does not contain an SDK.

Any help would be welcome.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio : goto File->Open and select your folder with unzipped sdk.
There's a tutorial for OpenXR [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJyUvi59hMA)

Comment: Video is no longer available.